# How to increase width and height to loading message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Problem is** : while loading the page we are displaying loading message,in that time
behind the messge anything is noneditable user should not click anything.
but if the page having large data then  if i scrolldown the page while loading it is are editable and user is able to click. how to apply loading to entire screen. I want full screen as noneditable without disabling scroll for that reason i need set hieght,width as full screen is there any code?
please let me know is there any problem in my code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
            function hideLoadingDIV1() {
                document.getElementById('LoadingDIV').style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>

<body onload="hideLoadingDIV1();">
<div class="container loader1" id="LoadingDIV">
            <div class="loader1-inner">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>&nbsp;Loading Please wait...</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have to use overlay

Comment: Set it as absolute, ``left: 0; top: 0;`` and then make sure with is ``100vw`` and height is ``100vh`` Make ``overflow: hidden`` to disable scroll.

Comment: I want to full screen as noneditable without disabling scroll is there any code? @Crowes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position:fixed;` in combination with `top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;`. It will create a "blocking" layer that covers the whole screen, scroll will still be enabled, but the blocking layer will catch all clicks on the screen...

Notice in the demo, that the scroll is still enabled:

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

```html
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br /><button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<button>I'm a button, click me if you can!</button>
<br />
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot @Ronen Cypis, its working fine.. I changed my code as follows <div class="container loader1" id="LoadingDIV" style="position:fixed;">

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by combination of javascript and css.

Please check the demo below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.loader').show();
});
```

```css
.loader {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader" style="display:none">
<img src="http://agiledevelopers.in/outnabout/uploads/squares.gif"></div>
```